# UriInfo injection - not getting updated for new requests

Tags: java, websphere, cxf, jax-rs

I'm having trouble in getting the correct absolute path/base path from UriInfo object which gets injected. These values for the very first request are right, but the subsequent requests still show the same value as the very first one. 
This becomes an issue when the requests differ in ports (http/https) or in the server name (ip/fqdn).
I use IBM websphere v8.0 with apache cxf.

Is this behavior intentional ? Or is there some config i can set to get this injected for all requests ?

```
public Response getVal (@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what the problem is unless you provide more information. You talk about different ports and host names. Why do they differ?

Comment: the first request i get after the application server is up is - https://myserver.com:443/root/service1. Here when i get absolute path from UriInfo it gives a right value. But the second request is send to the ip address of the same server - https://x.x.x.x:443/root/service1. But when I get the absolute path from UriInfo, it still has myserver in it instead of ip address x.x.x.x. Similar issue with localhost as well. Every new request gives the absolute path of the very first request always.

Hope this is the info you asked for.

Comment: How did you get past this?